# How to understand a line of dead code in a python function?

Tags: python, ply, dead-code

The following code comes from Ply, python’s lexer and parser. I understand the first line is a raw string but I also feel that the first line of the code looks like dead code and will be discarded in execution. How could I understand that line of code?

```
def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")
```

Comment: I think your understanding is correct, but if you're in doubt, you could try deleting it and seeing if the code behaves any differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a docstring, so that's not "dead code".

```
>>> def t_newline(t):
...     r'\n'
...     t.lexer.lineno += 1
... 
>>> t_newline.__doc__
'\\n'
```

[`ply.lex`](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/66369a66fa85981ab7a5e1dffd4ff7109bf4fa54/src/ply/lex.py#L323-L330) consumes them.

Comment: Do you mean that the lexical analysis will still work even if we remove it?

Comment: No. That's the opposite of what I mean. The regex for a t_rule is collected from this docstring attribute, and it is [an error condition](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/blob/66369a66fa85981ab7a5e1dffd4ff7109bf4fa54/src/ply/lex.py#L609-L612) if that's not present.

Answer (score 1):

That line of code is actually documentation for the function (although its meaning isn't too clear).  It populates the `.__doc__` property of the function itself.  Perhaps the `.__doc__` property is used somewhere else in the code.

If you write:

```
def myFunc():
    'This is my function, it always returns 3'
    return 3
```

you will get:

```
print(myFunc.__doc__)

This is my function, it always returns 3
```

Comment: It is (mis)used to hold the regex defining the token in ply's lexer.